# list(t) always returns the last item (class) entered

Tags: list, class

I am trying to to use list(of someclass) to keep track of an array of simular data for use at a later time in the program by using the .add() property.  When I do I always get back the last item entered.

```
Dim lst as new list(of superclass)
Dim work as new list(of superclass)
```

Program execution to fill work before storage.

```
Lst.add(work)
```

Then list the list

```
For each wrk in lst
  Print(lst)
Next
```

Comment: Your question is not that clear regarding when the "last item" is returned. Is it in the "list the list" code?

Answer (score 2):

Try printing `wrk` instead of `lst`.